# Is it possible to add more than one TableLayout in a LinearLayout with a ScrollView in Android development?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-tablelayout

I have this nice android app made up and was going to add in some finishing touches, one of which includes a page with two tables, and found that I can't make it happen. Basically I am trying to make a table with some values (across 4 or 5 columns) and then make another table below of different values (with only 2 columns). The tables will exceed the screen so it needs a ScrollView. However when I put all this together I get an error: ScrollView can host only one direct child. I have tried putting it in a LinearLayout. That does nothing either. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use more TableLayout but you need only one parent layout in the scrollview

```
<Scrollview>
      <LinearLayout> //parent layout
          <TableLayout>
           <TableRow></TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
           <TableLayout>
          <TableLayout>
         </TableLayout>
        </TableLayout>
     <LinearLayout>
<Scrollview>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have actually tried this. I suppose it is true but the layout always gets thrown off. For example, in the first few rows of the first table(with 4 columns) the text is right-aligned but when I try to align the other table(with 2 columns) it never aligns right. Any ideas???

Comment: for that you need to use android:layout_span http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_span

Comment: I FINALLY figured it out(after WAY TOO MUCH digging around and trial and error... (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻). Anyway, I found that after having the setup like you describe above the scrollview works fine with multiple tables. I couldn't get the text to line up though and found that adding android:stretchColumns="*" to TableLayout will make the rows columns stretch out fill the entire space, making the text fill the row completely! Thanks again